# is it legal to store jquery reference?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var global_ref = null;

function a(){
    function some_click_handler {
        global_ref = $(this);
    }
}

// later in 
function b()
{
    $(global_ref).css(...) // or global_ref.css(...) ???
}
```

Is above concept right? and the syntax right?

Comment: Call the cops, Bin Chen is using globals! :)

Comment: oh, yes i am doing criminals !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `$( global_ref )`, as `global_ref` is already a jQuery object.

That being said, relying on globals like that is a bad practice, but it will work (assuming `b()` is always called after `a()`)

Comment: what is better idea? I want to store the current popup div into the global variable so that if another popup is going to show we can close this previous popup.

Comment: Well at the very least you should create a "registry" class of sort that will hold your global variables so that you have them under your own "namespace" and you don't "pollute" the global "namespace".

Comment: @Bin You could set a class to the pop-up (like "activePopup"). Then you can select it later and hide it: `$(".activePopup").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring some syntax errors this is certainly legal. But you just need `global_ref.css(...)` as after `global_ref = $(this)` it is already a reference to a jQuery object